# How to simulate touch Event in Android Java

Tags: java, android

I want to build app that can simulate touch event each 1 min, i read somewhere that the phone should be rooted i want to do that without root

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to simulate touch for any application in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25495234/how-to-simulate-touch-for-any-application-in-android)

Comment: This is very broad. Do you want it to be done inside  your own app ? Or do you want this to be done automatically regardless of the app ? If that's the case, this question does not belong on SO.

Comment: @ArthurAttout i want this to be done automatically regardless of the app

Comment: Then, this question is unfortunately [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). IMO this belongs on [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/)